# Do actions on Meta count toward obtaining hats?

Tags: support, meta, winter-bash

I can see I have the same hats on Meta Stack Overflow and on Stack Overflow. But can my actions on Meta generate points towards giving me hats?

For example, if I (supposedly) ask this question exactly at 7pm in any timezone, will I get the *Hero Of Time* hat (and be able to answer my own question)?

I guess I could say this post is getting pretty "meta"...

Comment: I've seen a cross dupe feature request about that recently.

Comment: @user0042 me too, but it might've been deleted. I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't. As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/295232):

> Most hats are awarded for things you do on the main site, but there are a few that are awarded for performing an action on the site's meta. Their requirement generally includes the words "on meta". You still earn these hats *on the main site*, but you earn them for doing something on its child meta.

Sometimes, there are exceptions, but they are explicitly mentioned in the hat description, like last year's [I Am Your Father](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288344/295232).

Answer (score -12):

I didn't get it. So that means I won't get "Sherlock" badge with this answer either :'/

Comment: Unless there is a secret for getting a -10 answer on Meta ....

Comment: That could've been just because you weren't patient enough.